# Active Record and multi threading involving multiple dbs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails app that is multi homed.

`foo.mysite.com` talks to the "foo" db.

`bar.mysite.com` talks to the "bar" db.

This is accomplished by calling:

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection_handler.establish_connection("ActiveRecord::Base", foo_spec)`

When requests come in for foo it uses the foo_spec, when requests come in for bar it uses the bar_spec.

Everything is happy and there is peace in the world.

However,

I also use `sidekiq`, it is heavily multi-threaded.

I was getting weird behavior in sidekiq. Often when I thought I was talking to the foo_db, `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` was pointed at bar_db.

I dug into the code and found:

```
 def retrieve_connection_pool(klass)
    pool = @class_to_pool[klass.name]
    return pool if pool
    return nil if ActiveRecord::Base == klass
    retrieve_connection_pool klass.superclass
  end
```

Turns out the internal design of AR only allows AR::Base to know about a single connection pool.

Is there any way to get thread 1 to talk to db1, and thread 2 to talk to a db2 at the same time, using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` ?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using Postgres and separate schemas rather than separate databases entirely; that was you can share pools.

Usage would look like: `select * from foo.users`, `select * from bar.users`

And you would pass the schema to your background worker as an argument.